# mysql join table where foreign key is primary key of same table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have table of users(common for employee and manager) where `user_id` is primary key.

This table have rows of employees and one column with name 'Is manager' and value is Yes or No.

So when I create employee, I have option to select user's manager from same(user) table, inshort manager is one of person from users table. So this employee will get ID from users table (so reference will go to same table)

Problem is:
When I pull all users I also want to print manager's name as well in table.
How can I do that?

Earlier I had separate table of manager where I was using join command for getting manager information, how to join from same table?

### Thank you in advance.

I am adding my table and output requirement,

### manager_id 2 refers to row 2 of same column,

### | user_id | user_firstname | user_lastname | manager_id

### |1        | Rox            | Toy           |2

### |2        | Mix            | Joy           |null

|3        | Iox            | Cil           |2

Now, i want to fetch records and show in html table like below,

---

### | emp_firstname | emp_lastname   | manager_firstname | manager_lastname

### | Rox            | Toy           |Mix                |Joy

| Iox            | Cil           |Mix                |Joy

i am using codeigniter framework

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IT WILL PROVIDE YOU ALL MANAGER NAME WITH USERID.

```
 SELECT MGR.`user_id`, MGR.`user_firstname` AS MANAGERNAME FROM user AS EMP JOIN user AS MGR
    ON MGR.`user_id` = EMP.`manager_id` ;
```

Comment: who the hell make vote down. Please clearly me why did you voted down.

Comment: was not me who downvoted, but question clearly states its same table, not two separate tables.

Comment: what is this PARENTID?

Comment: By modifying above code in below sequence i could get my results, --------              SELECT MGR.`user_id`,MGR.`user_firstname`,MGR.`user_lastname`, EMP.`user_firstname` AS Managerfirstname, EMP.`user_lastname` AS Managerlastname FROM ec_user AS EMP JOIN ec_user AS MGR ON EMP.`user_id` = MGR.`manager_id`

Answer (score -1):

Use Self Join For this

For example

```
SELECT a.column_name, b.column_name...
FROM table1 a, table1 b
WHERE a.common_field = b.common_field;
```

[For more information click here](https://bikashshaw.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/employee-id-employee-name-and-manager-id-self-join-sql-query-as-interview-question/)